# Skrollr: progress bar finishing long before the end of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, skrollr

So I'm new to Skrollr, and am trying to make sense of the Skrollr positions.

Now for some reason my data-start / data-top progress bar finishes long before the page's end is hit.

Here is the JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/t8bZy/2/

Here is the problematic line of code.

```
<div id="progress" data-start="width:0%; background:hsl(200, 100%, 50%);" data-end="width:100%; background:hsl(920, 100%, 50%);"></div>
```

Can someone please let me know why the bar ends so prematurely?

Comment: Do you really need those extra <br/>tags it seems that they are causing trouble in calculation check demo after removal of <br/> http://jsfiddle.net/t8bZy/5/show/

Comment: why is it working there, but not on my file system, or website properly? http://vrnp-forums.strange-coast.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fiddle uses `data-top` whereas your posted code has `data-end` (which works as expected) http://jsfiddle.net/t8bZy/6/